# How monitor iPhone 's background process?

Tags: ios, iphone

i wanna activate my app through the ibeacon device advertising, then my app monitor the advertise and will be active in background, but i don't know how long will it can be active. how monitor the background process? when the app's status is Active , until it's status is killed?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHpZq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides support for iBeacons that will let you monitor beacons even if your app is in the background, or not running at all. Take a look at `CLBeaconRegion` and the Core Location manager. You set up one or more beacon regions and ask the system to begin monitoring them.

(You'll have to ask the user for permission to monitor beacon regions before it will work. Otherwise your API calls will fail.)